# Manipulate Properties to Add Scroll Bars in Dynamic Object?

Tags: manipulate, front-end, dynamic, gui-construction

I am interested in trying to produce a dynamic object of a plot of 20 functions, where users are able to select one of 20 functions in given plot. Here is my oversimplified non-working code:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[function[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], {function, {g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, 
  g7, g8, g9, g10, g11, g12, g13, g14, g15, g16, g17, g18, g19, g20}, 
  ControlType -> CheckboxBar, BaselinePosition -> Center, 
  Method -> "Active", Appearance -> "Horizontal"}]
```

When one executes this piece of code, it is clear to note that the check boxes extend past the plot and the size of the dynamic object. Is there a `Manipulate` option that would enable me to list out the 20 functions so that one can scroll through the check boxes horizontally (with a scroll bar) and select the appropriate function they would like to see on the plot?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
Manipulate[Plot[function[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], 
 Pane[Control@{function, {g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7, g8, g9, g10, 
     g11, g12, g13, g14, g15, g16, g17, g18, g19, g20}, 
    ControlType -> CheckboxBar, BaselinePosition -> Center, 
    Method -> "Active", Appearance -> "Horizontal"},
  Full, Scrollbars -> {True, False}, AppearanceElements -> None]
 ]
```

[image]
You can change `Full` size spec of `Pane` to whatever fixed value you want.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I need!

One more question. How can you control the position of `Pane`? Thanks!

Comment: @Wilson You can use ControlPlacement option. You can always use `DynamicModule` and assemble elements however you like.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following will provide a starting point. I'd suggest that you first remove the extra formatting from the `CheckboxBar`, in particular the `Appearance -> "Horizontal"` part: this will allow Mathematic to format the list of functions over multiple rows and require no scrolling to reach all of them.

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[Evaluate@Through[function[x]], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}],
  {{function, {Sin}}, {Sin, Cos, Sinc, Tan}, ControlType -> CheckboxBar}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In the code above, `Through` allows you to apply the same argument to a list of functions contained in `function`; `Evaluate` is added so Plot will explicitly be aware of the fact that its argument is a list, and style the different plots accordingly.

As a starting point, I'd also suggest that you take a look at the values of `function` itself as they change with user selection, before working on the plotting.

---

If you want *only one* function plotted at a time, then `RadioButtonBar` would perhaps be a more appropriate control choice, as it allows for mutually exclusive selections, i.e. for only one function being selected at any time.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I am aware that my code isn't working and I don't need a fix for it since I have a bigger program that I am currently working on. This program has the same issues that I have in the example above. If we take your code and list 20 functions instead of 4 functions, you will see that the list extends the dynamic object. Is there a way to avoid this? Thanks!